# How to get Historical Price from a specific time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the price of a stock using `=googlefinance` from a time stamp? Dates are fairly easy but it does not seem possible to do times on days? for example if I wanted to look at `GOOG` for `10:00AM 21/12/2020`

```
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price","21/12/2020 10:00:00"),2,2)
```

That provides the stock for that date but not the time. I am not sure if it's possible but it would be very useful in a sheet I am making.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can only retrieve the closing price of a particular **day** or **days** but not specific times.

When you pass a historical data as an argument, google assumes that you are looking for the closing price. Therefore, if you choose either "price" or "close" for a past data, you will get the same results.

The official documentation for the attribute "close":

> "close" - The closing price for the specified date(s).

therefore getting the closing price of a particular time is not possible.

For example, this will return the price for each day, starting from 21st of December 2020 until 30 days later:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price","12/21/2020",30,1)
```

or this `=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","close","12/21/2020",30,1)`

[image]

you see that the closing price time is fixed at `16:00:00`.

If you want real time historical data you should look for other APIs that you may need to pay.

Answer (score -1):

### You can filter once you get the values

As an example, you can retrieve the prices at 13:xx:xx hs or 16:xx:xx hs by using regular expressions and [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price","12/22/2020",30,1), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 matches '.* 13:.*|.* 16:.*'", 0))`

Or you can filter just one specific hour:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price","12/22/2020",30,1), "SELECT * WHERE Col1 matches '.* 13:.*'", 0))`

### References

- [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)